# How do I download clone my repository from GitHub for maintenance?

Tags: git, laravel, github, ssh, git-bash

I wrote a laravel package which is being maintained on GitHub. I got a new PC, now I need to clone/download my project in a why that I am able to push/pull changes to my GitHub repository using the command-line.

I created a new [SSH key](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/) as the documents describes.
I tried to download the project with the `prefer-source` option like this 
    composer require vendor-name/project-name:dev-master --dev --prefer-source

Then, I changed my directory to `vendor/vendor-name/project-name`. When I tried to do `git status` just to see if the command works, I got the follow error

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

How can I download a maintainable copy correctly?

I always struggle when using git. I will appreciate a descriptive answer on the right way to download a maintainable project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466945/fastest-way-to-download-a-github-project

Comment: Did you spend any time searching SO for help before posting this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sure I did. Why waste my and others time. the URL you provided shows how to clone the repository to use in a project. I want to clone it so I can maintain it by using `git add`, `git commit`, `git push`

Comment: `As a convenience, cloning automatically creates a remote connection called origin pointing back to the original repository. This makes it very easy to interact with a central repository.`

Comment: You may be over thinking this: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository

Comment: Just to cover basics, did you do a git init in the local directory you are working in first?

Comment: @Scott If he clones he shouldn't need to use `git init`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen indeed I am over thinking the problem. This command seems to worked `git@github.com:VendorName/PackageName.git` thank you

Answer (score 0):

its occurred cause no git detected
if you use **window 7**, to check it if have git go to your

```
project->organize->folder and search option->view
```

unchecked hide empty drives in the computer
unchecked hide **extensions** for known file types
click show hidden files

try to git remote your project

**Sample:**

git remote https://aaa@bitbucket.org/masterishere/onlineaaaa.git