# How to download a package from GitHub

Tags: git, azure, github, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-bot-service

I know how to download a project from GitHub as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6466993/1232087). Working on [Microsoft Azure Bot Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/?view=azure-bot-service-3.0). And need to download a `package` that is for [Microsoft Bot Framework Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-emulator?view=azure-bot-service-3.0). The link for the download is given in the in the section `Download the Bot Framework Emulator` of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-emulator?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) Microsoft article. That link takes me to [this GitHub site](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases). But I'm not clear on how to download the package from there.

Answer (score 2):

The [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases) you are talking about is the GitHub release page for Microsoft's Bot Framework Channel Emulator which would help a developer to test the Bot locally.

You just need to identify your platform [Windows (botframework-emulator-setup-4.0.15-alpha.exe)/ Mac (botframework-emulator-4.0.15-alpha-mac.zip) / Linux (botframework-emulator_4.0.15-alpha_amd64.deb)], download the file and you're good to go.

An application will be installed on your machine and you will be able to debug your bot locally.

One added information: You'll be needing **Ngrok** for tunneling after you set up the Bot Framework Channel Emulator.

Comment: Following your instructions, I installed the emulator and sent a test message but it say `couldn't` send. I've just posted the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50378863/1232087).

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of the error log? It should be on the right hand side of the emulator. Also I can see that you have set your MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword to the _default_ value. Is it also the same in your code?

Comment: Another thing, can you please check the **PORT Number** in your code and in the emulator? Check whether they are same or not. They should be same.

And as per the your screenshot, I can see you have specified your messaging endpoint url to your project hosting URL. Ideally it should be: (http://localhost:PORT_NUMBER/api/messages)

not your project URL