# Looking for open source references for ebook programming in Android

Tags: android, open-source, epub

I'm looking for open source references for ebook reading applications in Android. Any reader that has understandable code will do. Thanks!

Comment: Free e-book downloader tool https://programmingbooks.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [CoolReader](http://coolreader.org/e-index.htm)?

### Common features, for all platforms

- epub (non-DRM), fb2, txt, rtf, html, chm, tcr, doc, pdb formats
  supported
- Pages or scroll view
- Table of contents
- Bookmarks
- Text search
- Hyphenation dictionaries
- Most complete FB2 format support: styles, tables, footnotes
- Additional fonts support (.ttf)
- Can read books from zip archives
- Automatic reformatting of .txt files (autodetect headings etc.)
- Styles can be customised in wide range using external CSS

### Android specific

- Page flipping animation.
- Built-in file browser, quick recent books access Day and night profiles (two sets of colors, background, backlight levels) Brightness adjustments by flick on left edge of
  screen
- Background texture (stretched or tiled) or solid color
- Paperbook-like page turning animation or "sliding page" animation
- Dictionary support (ColorDict, Fora Dictionary, Aard dictionary)
- Customizable tap zone and key actions
- Place additional textures to /sdcard/.cr3/textures/ -- to be used as tiled page backgrounds
- Place additional textures to /sdcard/.cr3/backgrounds/ -- to be used as stretched page backgrounds (/cr3/ directory can also be used instead of /.cr3/, and internal SD or internal storage instead of /sdcard/)
- TTS (text-to-speech) support Select text using double tap (optional)

Comment: Is it really an open - source, because I found it's exe(for windows) and .apk but **I was unable to find the source code of that apk**... Reply please...

Comment: @GAMA see [Cool Reader project on Git](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=git&group_id=191284)

Comment: this link provides some documentation I guess. I'm a newbie, so can you please provide the exact url? I followed 

https://github.com/amahule/CoolReader

but it gives exception as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212432/android-unsatisfiedlinkerror-library-not-found

Comment: @GAMA you can browse code here: http://crengine.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=crengine/crengine;a=tree, to download, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751227/how-to-download-source-from-github) question.

Comment: but http://crengine.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=crengine/crengine;a=tree is same as https://github.com/amahule/CoolReader... I've imported the project folder(android) in eclipse. It don't throw any compile error but throws the run-time exception `FATAL EXCEPTION: BackgroundThread405310e8 , 
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load cr3engine: findLibrary returned null`

Comment: @GAMA ok, there is some native android project you should build first to get a lib: https://github.com/amahule/CoolReader/tree/master/android/jni

Comment: `jni` folder already exists in my project folder. How can I individually build it?

Comment: Please help. I'm no idea how to resolve this?

Comment: @GAMA you will need [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html), see also [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/ndk-tutorial/)

Comment: you have also futurepress/epub.js : it reads epub and annotation through a web browner

Answer (score 1):

I think this Application is useful for you: [FBReader](https://github.com/geometer/FBReaderJ)

Comment: i had downlode this project but it display error on project can you help me to fix error.

Answer (score 0):

[daisy_epub](http://code.google.com/p/android-daisy-epub-reader/) seems to match your 'understandable' Criteria

Comment: How do I access their trunk? It's asking for a password

Comment: "# Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.
svn checkout http://android-daisy-epub-reader.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ android-daisy-epub-reader-read-only
"

Comment: @RafaelT can you tell me which epub file is running in above code becuase i had downloded epub file with image and other epub file also so if you know then please help me.
Thanks