# Lib not found error in tesseract

Tags: android, ocr

I am working with OCR android. Got samples from googling and work with android tesseract. I have the project as library and refered in another project but, when I run the project it shows the following in Logcat

```
 07-17 10:38:47.092: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(426): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-17 10:38:47.092: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(426): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    07-17 10:38:47.092: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(426):     at com.imagetotext.ImagetoText.onCreate(ImagetoText.java:21)
    07-17 10:38:47.092: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(426):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    07-17 10:38:47.092: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(426):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
    07-17 10:38:47.092: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(426):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    07-17 10:38:47.092: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(426):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
    07-17 10:38:47.092: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(426):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    07-17 10:38:47.092: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(426):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    07-17 10:38:47.092: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(426):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    07-17 10:38:47.092: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(426):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    07-17 10:38:47.092: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(426):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-17 10:38:47.092: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(426):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    07-17 10:38:47.092: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(426):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    07-17 10:38:47.092: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(426):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    07-17 10:38:47.092: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(426):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-17 10:38:47.092: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(426): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library liblept not found
    07-17 10:38:47.092: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(426):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:461)
    07-17 10:38:47.092: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(426):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
    07-17 10:38:47.092: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(426):     at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(TessBaseAPI.java:47)
    07-17 10:38:47.092: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(426):     ... 14 more
    07-17 10:38:47.112: WARN/ActivityManager(60):   Force finishing activity com.imagetotext/.ImagetoText
```

I think there is something wrong with my android.mk. Please help me fix the error.

Comment: Look at your library is there **liblept.so** file available?

Comment: no there is no lib directory in that file

Comment: How to get that .so file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212432/android-unsatisfiedlinkerror-library-not-found

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865464/android-tesseract-force-close?rq=1

Comment: I had the same problems. Solution was switching from x64-JDK to x86-JDK. Under x64, my program wasn't able to load the native while they were written for x86 architecture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exception cause line is,

```
System.loadLibrary(“lept”);
```

The problem is **liblept.so** (shared library) file can not found on specific library path. Without seeing your code just only assumption is your code trying to load shared library **liblept.so** and the library is not available at that path.

Also the code you are using is either have that **liblept.so** file in any `lib` or `internal package directory` or you have to generate (build) that shared library by using **Android-NDK**.

Comment: yes, now only i realise. Is any way to build .so file through command. I use eclipse.

Comment: @Shalini you'll need to use Android-NDK to build `liblept.so`, then use Eclipse to build your application.

Comment: am new to ndk and jni. need any good referal link to build .so file. please

Comment: Use latest [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) and android developer guide. Now its so easy to build library using ndk. [NDK-Tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/ndk-tutorial/)

Comment: Trying this in IntelliJ IDEA instead of Eclipse. Please reopen the question.

Comment: i tried building the application in eclipse with ndk support but the so file is not generated, infact it doesnt even show that it has native support, any suggestions?