# Couldn't load lept from loader findLibrary returned null?

Tags: android, ocr

HI am working on **OCR**(Optical Character Recognization) i got a sample project from github.For this project am using tess-test library project and the project builds and executes successfully but whenever the TessBaseAPI is called the app stopped unfortunately..and it shows the following log error

```
12-20 18:27:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(24466): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
12-20 18:27:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(24466):    at com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple.SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.onPhotoTaken(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.java:211)
12-20 18:27:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(24466):    at com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple.SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.onActivityResult(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.java:135)
12-20 18:27:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(24466):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5293)
12-20 18:27:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(24466):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3315)
12-20 18:27:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(24466):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3362)
12-20 18:27:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(24466):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-20 18:27:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(24466):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
12-20 18:27:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(24466):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-20 18:27:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(24466):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-20 18:27:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(24466):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-20 18:27:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(24466):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 18:27:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(24466):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-20 18:27:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(24466):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-20 18:27:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(24466):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-20 18:27:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(24466):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-20 18:27:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(24466): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load lept from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple-1]: findLibrary returned null
12-20 18:27:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(24466):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
12-20 18:27:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(24466):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
12-20 18:27:18.791: E/AndroidRuntime(24466):    at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(TessBaseAPI.java:47)
```

please give solution to my problem am stucked from 5 days it is required in my application.

i googled a lot didn't find any solution..
Thank You

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lib not found error in tesseract](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516440/lib-not-found-error-in-tesseract)

Answer (score 11):

Make sure that the library file *"liblept.so"* exist either in *libs/armeabi* or *libs/armeabi-v7a*, if they exists there, use 7Zip/WinRAR to open the generated APK file and make sure it exists in the APK as well.

Answer (score 0):

duplicate of [Lib not found error in tesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516440/lib-not-found-error-in-tesseract)

The problem is liblept.so (shared library) file can not found on specific library path. Without seeing your code just only assumption is your code trying to load shared library liblept.so and the library is not available at that path.

Also the code you are using is either have that liblept.so file in any lib or internal package directory or you have to generate (build) that shared library by using Android-NDK.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you found the answer to your problem but mine was from the libs folder in my project being incorrectly named (was lib instead of libs). My issue was a result of accidentally deleting my project and having to restore it by extracting the APK from my phone. Once I renamed the folder, my issue was solved. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ppl, After struggling a day.. finally got the solution

In build.gradle of tess-two module add the below code:

```
  sourceSets.main {
    manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
    java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
    resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
    res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
    jni.srcDirs = []
    jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
}
```

Main thing is please check manually weather all those file paths specified in above code exists!!

Coming to this issue, check where "**liblept.so**" exist in tess-two library.
For me it was inside */tesstwo/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a* . Hence i have made **jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']** in above code. Hope it helps !!