# simple copy of github working copy

Tags: git, github, repository

I want to make a copy of the current working copy of a github repository.

To clarify: I don't want to make a copy of the entire repository, and the entire history, of a project. I don't care about the history.

I simply want to "check out" a working copy of the current state to compile locally.

As much as this seems like it should be simple, I haven't found anything on this. Everything seems to be about getting a complete historical copy of all the data, and that's not what I'm interested in.

How can this be done?

Comment: On project page in github you have "zip" button, thanks to it you can download repo as zip.

Comment: why not just zip the file?
https://github.com/[user-name]/[repo-name]/archive/master.zip

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download source in .zip format from GitHub?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751227/how-to-download-source-in-zip-format-from-github)

Answer (score 0):

Click the `zip` button on the repository page.

Answer (score 0):

why not just zip the file?

Try this:

https://github.com/[user-name]/[repo-name]/archive/master.zip

Answer (score 0):

I think 
  git archive 
is the command you need.
It will create a zip or tar file containing the version you specify!
It has many different interesting options too and can work on local or remote repositories.

Answer (score 0):

"Current working copy" is checked out directory, maybe containing local changes. You can zip it like any other directory. To drop history, skip .git directory.

If you want to create snapshot from some commit, git archive is the right tool. You can also clone with --depth option to skip downloading of entire history.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want using the `--depth` option to `git clone`.

> `--depth <depth>`
>
> Create a shallow clone with a history truncated to the specified number of revisions. A shallow repository has a number of limitations (you cannot clone or fetch from it, nor push from nor into it), but is adequate if you are only interested in the recent history of a large project with a long history, and would want to send in fixes as patches.

Note the limitations, which may be no problem for a one–shot build.

For example

```
$ git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2.git

$ git log
commit 97d32abb492f7830f6e26719ce558429f6377b73
Author: Carlos Martín Nieto 
Date:   Wed Oct 30 15:09:32 2013 +0100

    Remove leftover function declaration
```