# iOS 5 and above: enable landscape mode in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, video

I have an application entirely in portrait mode. (iOS 5 and above)
I have a video played using MPMoviePlayerController, now in this video i want that when user rotates the iPhone, the video should go to landscape mode(in fullscreen).
When video ends , again the video should go into portrait mode.
Code:

```
    -(void)PlayVideo:(NSURL*)videoUrl
{


    moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoUrl];
    [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(6, 69, 309, 196)];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    //    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;


    moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.shareView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.qualityView];

    [moviePlayerController play];

    // Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayerController];

}
```

Rest of the app, i want in portrait only.
How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

First you need to set Support interface orientation to **Portrait** as well as **Landscape**

[image: As shows here]

Now in every UIViewController you need to override these methods -

for **iOS 5** -

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
```

for **iOS 6**

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

In UIViewController where you are going to add MPMoviePlayerController override -

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

Comment: but by doing this, all other controls in the viewController having the moviePlayer will also be in landscape mode, i want only the movieplayer to be in landscape

Comment: then you can check in `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate` (**iOS 5**) `-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations` (**iOS 6**) whether moviePlayer is full screen or not. If full screen then return `YES` otherwise return `NO`. Check using `[moviePlayer isFullscreen]`

Comment: and i should implement - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
in every controller?

Comment: unfortunately but yes.

Comment: when i write : `- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}` , in the viewcontroller having moviePlayer, i can still rotate to landscape. How do i solve this?

Comment: Are you using UINavigationController for navigating through application?

Comment: no i am using revealSideViewController, no navogationController

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520030/how-to-force-a-uiviewcontroller-to-portait-orientation-in-ios-6 . It helped me hope it will be helpful for you too.

Comment: i saw the link, but i haven't used navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

I created Xcode project with sample of the video player. It can show video on full screen in landscape mode. You can [download it](https://github.com/SKrotkih/VideoPlayer) . I hope it helps you.

And second. Instead of

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.shareView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.qualityView];
```

you should write like this:

```
    [moviePlayerController.view insertSubview: self.shareView
                                      atIndex: 2];

    [moviePlayerController.view insertSubview: self.qualityView
                                      atIndex: 2];
```

then shareView and qualityView appears on top of the movie player.

Comment: hey thanks, but i can't unzip the file after downloading, seems there is some error with the zip

Comment: please read answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751227/how-to-download-source-from-github

Comment: @stosha- good one. **z22** i think this is what you are looking for. it worked on my MAC.

Comment: @z22 have you any problem? i can send the project by email.

Comment: @stosha sure that would be great, id: user8.lanetteam@gmail.com