# How to download source in .zip format from svn?

Tags: svn, boost

To download the boost trunk as zip from [boost trunk](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/)

Right now, I am checking out files using SharpSvn in my c# code, but it would be great if there is way to get the boost trunk as a zip similar to GitHub as mentioned in another post: [How to download source in ZIP format from GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751227/how-to-download-source-in-zip-format-from-github)

Comment: For both Git and SVN, this is something the *server* can do as an added function, but is not a part of the source control system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can't get** automagically **any URL** in Subversion repository compressed into **any type of archive**. Period

Comment: You'd be a **lazier** badger **iff** you had **refrained** from all the **markdown** emphasis

Comment: @Lazy Badger: Yes, I accept but like other post on github suggested to get zip file by adding zipball/master/ at the end of URL, which I was not aware of.

Comment: @Asterisk14 - only for Github and just because it's Git behind the scene for both access-URLs