# Using GitHub Pages to serve files (i.e. zip)

Tags: github, github-pages

I have setup GitHub pages and my site is working fine, but when navigating to the zip file at the site (i.e. `mysite.com/example.zip`), I get 404 error page. The files are in the repository and it seems that for some files it works as I can access PDF file just fine (i.e. `mysite.com/myfile.pdf`). Couldn't find any mention that GitHub Pages are blocking this, but seems like it, or am I missing something? Is there a list of files which ones are served and which not?

Comment: this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751227/how-to-download-source-in-zip-format-from-github) may be helpful for you.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't as the question there is about downloading repository as zip file. I want to serve custom zip files via my GitHub Pages