# How to identify the repository url without Git installation?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, repository

How to identify the Github url to the downloaded repository without having the Git installed on the system?

Comment: I don't understand the question, sorry. GitLab and GitHub both show the link without cloning the repository. If you already have a clone, look in the `.git/config` file. Also, the text talks about "GitHub", but the tags include "GitLab" too – which one is it?

Comment: @nik Did you resolved your issue?

Comment: Thank you. I got the url mentioned in .git/config :
[remote "origin"]
 url = forkUrl 
[remote "upstream"]
 url = repoUrl

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you have downloaded the repository.

If you have used the ["Download zip" file from a GitHub repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61459303/6309), you can get the sources without having Git installed, but you don't have the full history, *and* you don't have the `.git/config` with the remote URL in it.

So with just a copy of the sources, you cannot say for sure from which remote repository hosting site said sources are coming from.