# how to do checkout in github actions on remote server which is running somewhere using ssh?

Tags: ssh, github-actions, remote-access, cicd, git-checkout

Let's say there are two machines A and B, I'm inside **A** machine which works as a self-hosted runner in the GitHub actions. If I use checkout action, it will checkout to **Machine A**, what if I want checkout to **Machine B** by ssh to **Machine B** without git clone or appleboy/ssh-action.

Example Workflow:

```
....
....
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: self-hosted [Machine A]
    steps:
      - name: checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2 
        #Which will checkout in A
      - name: ssh
        #lets say I ssh to remote Machine B
        and able to run the commands inside the B how to do the 
        checkout in B other than git clone. Is it possible??
```

Comment: What kind of connectivity you have with Machine B if it's not SSH?

Comment: Is it now clear regarding my question? sry for that

Comment: So, you want to use SSH directly. Well, you'll have to do something to get your code there. If your don't want to use `git clone` or related commands, you may simply download your code archive there. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2751270/7670262.